# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pixelengine' in python

Tags: python-3.x

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pixelengine' in python while converting the phiips isyntax format file into OME-TIFF.**

By following this documentation https://www.glencoesoftware.com/blog/2019/12/09/converting-whole-slide-images-to-OME-TIFF.html#footnotes

I used python 3.6 in ubuntu 18.04.

First I download and install the [philips sdk](https://www.philips.co.in/healthcare/sites/pathology/release-press/20190806-philips-pathology-sdk-now-available-to-software-developers-and-scientists)  as per given instruction in documentation.

Then I downloaded [isyntax2raw](https://github.com/glencoesoftware/isyntax2raw) and install it.

After executing this command in terminal
**isyntax2raw write_tiles 20200207_140740.isyntax  /home/user/**

The error comes

**Traceback** (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dilip/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/isyntax2raw", line 11, in 
    load_entry_point('isyntax2raw==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'isyntax2raw')()
  File "/home/dilip/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/dilip/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2859, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/dilip/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2450, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/dilip/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2456, in resolve
    module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)
  File "/home/dilip/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/isyntax2raw-0.0.0-py3.6.egg/isyntax2raw/**init**.py", line 15, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pixelengine'

Answer (score 0):

Since a few months Philips has added some sample scripts to transform isyntax to TIFF, extract patches, or visualize.
To access these scripts you have to create an account on [openpathology](https://www.openpathology.philips.com) and then go to the [SDK](https://www.openpathology.philips.com/pathologysdk/) section.